# MATLAB: can I somehow use functions as first class objects?

Tags: matlab, function, function-pointers

I have a use case where I need to compute a variable based on a user selected number of basis functions. For example if the user specified `num_basis_funcs = 4`:

```
y = const() + linear(x) + rational1(x) + sin(x)
      1          2            3            4
```

If the user specifies `num_basis_funcs = 2`, then `y` would only be computed as:

```
y = const() + linear(x)
      1          2
```

If the user specifies `num_basis_funcs = 1`, then `y` would only be computed as:

```
y = const()
      1
```

I have selected some simple basis functions only for the sake of example; suffice it to say that in the full application, these basis functions will be user defined.

Coming from Python, what comes to my mind is making a list of functions, which I apply selectively based on user input. Coming from a C++ angle, what comes to mind is using function pointers to pass which function should be executed.

In general, how can I pass around functions as "first class objects" in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html?refresh=true). I would recommend passing a cell array of function handles and evaluating them in a loop like so:

```
function out = evalFns(x, fnCell)
out = 0;
for iFn = 1:length(fnCell)
    out = out + fnCell{iFn}(x);
end
```

Which you would call via `y = evalFns(x, {@const, @linear, @rational, @sin})`.